# Why doesn't this return the value inside of the 'plaque' class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following is an html excerpt:

```
<div class="content cardlisting small">
    <div class="collectionbox">
        <div class="leftcontent">
            <div>Collection Status</div>
                <div>You must be logged in to track your collection</div>
            </div>
        <div class="checkcontrols">
            <button class="checkall" title="Add all cards to your collection" onclick="collectionManager.toggleAllCheckboxes( '320', true );">Check All</button>
            <button class="checknone" title="Remove all cards from your collection" onclick="collectionManager.toggleAllCheckboxes( '320', false );">Check None</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
        <span class="checkbox" id="checkbox39007" title="Toggle Card in Collection" data-cardid="39007" onclick="collectionManager.toggleCheckbox( this );"></span>
        <span class="zoom" title="quick view card" onclick="siteOverlay.show('/ajax/views/card-overlay?cardid=39007');"></span>
        <a href="" name="" title="">
            <img class="card lazyloaded" data-src="" src="">
        </a>
        <div class="plaque">#1 - Weedle</div>
    </div>
```

I am beginning to learn scraping with python and I have put together the following python file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Collect the page
page = requests.get('www.somesite.com') #not a real site
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
cards = soup.find(class_="content cardlisting small")
cards_list = cards.find_all(class_='plaque')
print(len(cards_list)
for cards in cards_list:
    cards_name = cards.find(class_='plaque')
    print(cards_name)
```

The python file is finding all the plaque elements and adding them to the cards_list variable in the code. It returns the length of the list as well. The problem is in the loop. I have tried to append .text to the `cards.find(class_='plaque)` line and get an error saying there is no such attribute. What I'm wanting is to extract the data inside of the html element. In this case it should return #1 - Weedle. In the current state of the code, the value that is returned is 'None' for each element in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: `cards_list` already has the set of `plaque` elements.  You don't want to search again inside the list.  Instead, just `.text` to grab the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and that certainly does what I was wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open("1.html", encoding="utf8")     
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

for cls in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "plaque"}):
    print(cls)
```

output:

```
<div class="plaque">#1 - Weedle</div>
```